# MySQL processlist history maintainence

Tags: python, mysql, database

I was thinking of writing a tool to maintain history of queries taking longer than **5** seconds.

Tool back end setup will look like:

```
Table1:QUERY_META  
queryId int() (PK)  
query text  
regDate date  

Table2: QUERY_STAT  
queryId: int() (FK)  
runDate: date (date of Run)  
avgTimeTaken:int()  
noOfRuns: int()
```

To make it "smart", I was hoping to maintain only unique queries. What I mean by that is, suppose I have queries like:

a) `SELECT a,b,c from table1 where x='x1' and y != 'y1';` (10 seconds)
   b) `SELECT a,b,c from table1 where x='x2' and y != 'y2';` (10 seconds)

Now essentially, I'll like to store query like:

```
SELECT a,b,c from table1 where x = <x> and y != <y>;
```

This'll make life easier to see how many of the same kind of queries are running.

What it means for my tool to do is: **normalize** the where clause.
I can **split** at the keyword **WHERE**, and that's where my problem becomes big. How can I normalize/standardize the where clause?
There are quite a few comparison operators and I don't know easy way to do string manipulations. I am not worrying about multiple where clauses as of now.

I consider myself to be proficient using Python, MySQL (but open to anything that gets the job done).

My fallback plan is banking on the `select` and adding a `queryTag` column on `QUERY_META` table. It'll work as a psuedo-group by column! There are complications here too, but typing that all here will lengthen the already long post.

I cannot use slow query logs for this purpose, due to audience of the tool and some system limitations.

If there is a tool that already does that, please point me towards it, because I was having hard time identifying what to google for.

Answer (score 0):

There is an incredible tool called [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html) from Percona.  It does everything you want and more.  I have always used it with the slow query logs, but it has other options.  From the help:

> pt-query-digest is a sophisticated but easy to use tool for analyzing
>   MySQL queries. It can analyze queries from MySQL slow, general, and
>   binary logs. (Binary logs must first be converted to text, see
>   --type). It can also use SHOW PROCESSLIST and MySQL protocol data from tcpdump. By default, the tool reports which queries are the slowest,
>   and therefore the most important to optimize. More complex and
>   custom-tailored reports can be created by using options like
>   --group-by, --filter, and --embedded-attributes.

Be sure to check out the options for --group-by as they are very powerful.